# Why does JqxTreeGrid not allow browser selection when selectionMode is singleRow?

Tags: javascript, jqwidget, jqxtreegrid

In a `jqxTreeGrid`, I can set the `enableBrowserSelection` property to `true` to allow selection of (parts of) the text displayed in the cells. This is useful for copying the data to the clipboard.

However, I noticed that this does not work when I set `selectionMode` to `singleRow`.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/8wY9T/) as an example: As soon as I add `selectionMode: "singleRow",` to the JavaScript (e.g. line 143), browser selection is no longer working.

Is this a bug or is there a reason behind it which I do not understand?

Comment: In the code I read: if (f.selectionMode === "singlerow" && f.selectionMode !== "custom") { f.selectrowbykey(F, "mouse", false);.....Hence, I assume it is not a bug